# Elasticsearch returns wrong count

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an es index with a document route and has 3 items in it.
Eg schema :

```
document {
   name
   items [] (list of strings)
}
```

eg data when I retrieve something with size x :

```
[
{ name : a , item : [ 'blue', 'green' ] } ,
{ name : b , item : [ 'blue', 'yellow' ] } ,
{ name : c , item : [ 'red', 'back' ] } ,
]
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is query document and get the count of all the items in it. In the above case there are 3 items.

When I do a count query I get a weird overblown result. Is it because my document doesn't have a unique id identifier ?

Is there a way to get the right count ?

Comment: Please show your query

Comment: If your document does not have unique identifier, they are overwritten, so yes that could be the reason.

Comment: @Val Hey, so it was due to the id not being present. Can one of you explain how es handles documents which don't have an id ? When you reindex an item ? It saves the old copy and adds a new copy which seems to be the case but the old copy is not returned but probably cached. Is that true ? How does ES do this ?

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel FYI